# found values of dataframe in other dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, comparator

I have two data frames that could be called "a" and "b". Each with one column. I would like to find the values ​​of "a" to "b". Then I wanted to save the values ​​found in a dataframe, and save the values ​​that have not been found in another data frame.

What would be the best way? Is there any function to do this job?

thank you very much

Comment: What do you mean by "the values of a to b"? If you give a small example we are much better placed to help you.

Comment: example: a = c(1,2,3,4) and b = c(1,3,6,7,9,6,1), I want a function that compares two dataframes and I return the values ​​that are in both.